# How do I receive/import shared data in an iOS App using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I apologize in advance because I feel like this should be available somewhere, but I can't find it. We have a messaging/mail app and we want to receive shared data. I see UIActivityViewController but that is for sharing with others. How do you actually receive the data? I mean if someone has an image that want to share with us, how do we get it and register ourselves as being able to take it?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to implement Share Extension**

> Please follow below link to implement the `share extension`
>
> http://www.yudiz.com/share-extention-in-ios-app/

After implementation, Others can see your app in `UIActivityViewController` apps and they can share images and other things with you.